# How to use $sce.trustAsHtml when it contains <script> tags

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have an AngularJS component which loads HTML into its scope and uses `ng-bind-html`. I've noticed that `<script>` tags are not executing.

How can I get this example code to alert?

```
app.component('myComponent', {
    bindings: { 
        file: '<' 
    },
    controller: function($http, $sce) {
        var $ctrl = this;
        $ctrl.onChanges = function(changes) {
            $http.get($ctrl.file).then(function(response){
                $ctrl.html = $sce.trustAsHtml(response.data);
            });
        };
    },
    template: '<div><div ng-if="$ctrl.html" ng-bind-html="$ctrl.html"></div></div>'
});
```

The `$http` data that is being returned is:

`<div> I am html <script>alert('I am a script')</script></div>`

Or, what if I wanted to have a controller reference in the HTML?

`<div ng-controller="myController"> I am html</div>`

Comment: What's the overarching goal here?  I.e. why do you need to execute scripts in dynamically-loaded HTML?  This component seems fishy to me.  Can't you use standard AngularJS routing and load different templates and controllers for different routes?

Answer (score 1):

Behind the scenes, `$http.get` is simply using XMLHttpRequest.  Due to security constraints, and namely cross-site scripting, scripts added to the DOM dynamically (e.g. added after an XMLHttpRequest) do not execute.  Hence, the only way to execute the script within your HTML is to find the script tag in the result, then call `eval()` on the contents.

Comment: Thanks, @avejidah, what about including a controller as referenced in my updated post?

Comment: Using a controller in that manner is a different question.  However, I think you could `$compile` the result.  Take a look at the documentation for `$compile` and see if that solves the problem.

Comment: I take that back.  You can't, as far as I can tell, use `$compile` on the result and get the controller to execute dynamically.